# What are the steps needed to collaborate on an existing GitLab project?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, atom-editor

I need to modify an existing Project on GitLab which has many Repositories.

The Repository I need to modify has only the Master branch with only 1 file (the one which I'll be modifying).

I'm on Atom using the git-plus package, which steps should I do in order to get the Repository locally and perform changes to the remote repo after?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 1):

You should `git clone <remote_url>` the repo to your local machine, then `git branch <your_branch_name>` and then switch to it with `git checkout <your_branch_name>`. Now every commit will go to your new branch.

When you are done with your work and want to merge the changes to master, depending on your setup, you can simply merge or create a pull request and have the administrator verify it and then merge.

To merge to master, first switch to the master branch `git checkout master` and then `git merge <your_branch_name>`. Don't forget to `git push` to propagate the changes to remote.

If you are new with git, try this interactive tutorial to learn the basics: https://learngitbranching.js.org/